# How to create nested dictionaries with new name using for

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a new nested dicts with new name using for. F.e.

```
ne_d = { 'dict1': {'name': 'Laura', 'surname': 'Les'},
       'dict2': {'name': 'Bear', 'surname': 'Grills'}}
```

it is necessary that new dictionaries are created through the for loop or otherwise, but dict3, dict4, etc.

the output should be something like this

```
{ 'dict1': {'name': 'Laura', 'surname': 'Les'},
'dict2': {'name': 'Bear', 'surname': 'Grills'}}
'dict3': {'name': '111', 'surname': '222'}}
'dict4': {'name': '333', 'surname': '444'}}
etc.
```

Comment: Looks like you want a list at the outermost level, not a dictionary. Then you can just append a new dictionary.

Comment: and how to implement it?

Comment: `list_of_dictionaries.append({'name': '111', 'surname': '222'})`